# Error 404 to Storm Ui

Tags: apache-storm

I install Storm on Ubuntu 14.04 (on a virtual machine).

I also install apache2, and create a link in this directory :

```
ln -sf /usr/share/storm/public/    /var/www/html/
```

With this link I can access to my storm directory by tapping :
172.1.24.18/storm

But, I have 404 errors :
example : 
`GET http://172.25.31.45/api/v1/topology/summary 404 (Not Found)`

In fact, I think Storm use absolute path.
If you have an idea to create a redirection ...

Thanks

Comment: how did u start the UI? and how did you get the URL that showing 404. I don't think you need to install apache for accessing the UI page.

Comment: I start the ui with apache (link to the directory /usr/share/storm/public)
And with Chrome Inspection, I see some 404 errors...

Comment: start the UI using `bin/storm ui` command. Once done by default the UI will be available on `http://<your_nimbus_ip>:8080`  .

Comment: I use /bin/storm ui and supervisor and nimbus but it's the same...

Comment: Error like that :
`GET http://172.5.0.209/api/v1/cluster/summary 404 (Not Found)
jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18 
GET http://172.5.0.209/api/v1/topology/summary 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18 GET http://172.5.0.209/api/v1/supervisor/summary 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18 GET http://172.5.0.209/api/v1/cluster/configuration 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: once the UI is running you should be able to see it by typing the following URL in your browser.. http://<your_nimbus_ip>:8080 .. where <your_nimbus_ip> should be replace with the actual ip of your machine. Are you able to see that ? confirm that first . You DONT need to have apache installed / running in order to view that. If your nimbus is 172.5.0.209 then tell what did you see by typing http://172.5.0.209:8080

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i forgot the port number :8080 :)
Now, it runs ! :) Thanks